# Is there any way to undelete a field, but not through backups in Anki?

Tags: backup, anki

I deleted the field titled "Front" and "Back" accidentally from all my cards and now all of them are blank. I have tried to restore it from backups, but since I hadn't closed Anki for a couple of days it never backed up I guess. I have made over 300 cards in the past few days and I'm searching for any possible way to get those cards back. The last automatic back up Anki did was apparently right after I had deleted the fields. I tried restoring the cards from one of the backups, but just using a different profile, but that did not work. Is there any way to get my cards back, or am I just out of luck and need to remake all those cards? Please help! I'm willing to try anything because the cards are gone otherwise.

Comment: so you have an application that stores cards, and implements a database to hold them in. you manually edited that database to drop several fields, and you would now like them back, but have no backups. correct?

Comment: Pretty much yes, and I should have been more specific. These cards were stored in Anki and it backs up automatically whenever closed, but it hadn't been closed since I started, so it never backed up.